# Firebase Cloud Functions: Throw Https error inside try catch block

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, try-catch, throw

I use TypeScript in my callable Cloud functions. Their structure looks something like this:

```
exports.sayHello = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const email: string = data.email;
        const isStudent: boolean = data.isStudent

        if (isStudent) {
            const mathGrade: string = data.mathgrade;

            try {
                // Access Firestore
            } catch (error) {
                // Throw Https error
            }

        } else {
            const mainSubject: string = data.mainsubject;      
            try {
                // Access Firestore
            } catch (error) {
                // Throw Https error
            } 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle type error (the typecasting failed because of the json data)
    }
});
```

My question now is if the Https errors I throw would be caught by the outer try catch block, because what I want is send them to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be caught by the outer catch.